# 'UserDetailView' object has no attribute 'object_list'

Tags: django, pagination

everyone! In the user detail page I have user's posts, which I want to paginate(planning to make infinite pagination later on). Trying to to that, I get the error 'UserDetailView' object has no attribute 'object_list'. I was searching a lot for solution, but did not find clear example how to paginate related objects in detail view. Any help on this higly appreciated.

This is my DetailView for user:

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView,MultipleObjectMixin):
    model = CustomUser
    template_name = 'users/user_detail.html'
    context_object_name = "user"
    paginate_by = 5


    def get_object(self):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get('id')
        return get_object_or_404(CustomUser, id=id_)


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        posts = self.object.posts_set.all().order_by('-created_at')
        #context['posts'] = self.object.posts_set.all().order_by('-created_at')

        context = super(UserDetailView, self).get_context_data(posts=posts, **kwargs)

        context['main'] = Main.objects.get(pk=1)
        context['supporters'] = CustomUser.objects.filter(team = self.object.team)

        return context
```

And the error I get :
'UserDetailView' object has no attribute 'object_list'

**Traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/1/

Django Version: 3.0.7
Python Version: 3.8.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'team.apps.TeamConfig',
 'posts.apps.PostsConfig',
 'main.apps.MainConfig',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'rest_framework',
 'pytils']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py", line 107, in get
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\fansite\fantribune\users\views.py", line 66, in get_context_data
    context = super(UserDetailView, self).get_context_data(posts=posts, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py", line 100, in get_context_data
    return super().get_context_data(**context)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py", line 115, in get_context_data
    queryset = object_list if object_list is not None else self.object_list

Exception Type: AttributeError at /user/1/
Exception Value: 'UserDetailView' object has no attribute 'object_list'
```

Comment: The `MultipleObjectMixin` should be placed *before* the `DetailView`.

Comment: But it looks like this is actually a `ListView`.

Comment: It is DetailView - UserDetailView. In this DetailView there is a related object - Posts. So I need to make pagination for user posts, which are displayed in the  single user view page.

Comment: then why not make it a listview for the related object, and include details of the object in the view?

Comment: Thanks for advice. I found a solution, using DetailView. You may see it in my answer bellow.

Comment: but this not paginate the items, right?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. Below is the code. It might be useful for others.

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView,MultipleObjectMixin):
    model = CustomUser
    template_name = 'users/user_detail.html'
    context_object_name = "user"
    paginate_by = 5


    def get_object(self):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get('id')
        return get_object_or_404(CustomUser, id=id_)


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        object_list = Posts.objects.filter(author=self.get_object())
        #posts = self.object.posts_set.all().order_by('-created_at')
        context = super(UserDetailView, self).get_context_data(object_list=object_list,**kwargs)
        #context['posts'] = self.object.posts_set.all().order_by('-created_at')


        context['main'] = Main.objects.get(pk=1)
        context['supporters'] = CustomUser.objects.filter(team = self.object.team)

        return context
```

So, to paginate related objects in DetailView I added MultipleObjectMixin as a parameter:

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView,MultipleObjectMixin):
```

And than in get_context_data get the related model and defining the context super:

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        object_list = Posts.objects.filter(author=self.get_object())

        context = super(UserDetailView, self).get_context_data(object_list=object_list,**kwargs)

 #other code
```

and

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a listview, where you add the data of the `CustomUser` as well:

```
from django.db.models import get_object_or_404

class UserDetailView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'users/user_detail.html'
    paginate_by = 5
    context_object_name = 'posts'

    def get_queryset(self, *kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(**kwargs).filter(
            user_id=self.kwargs['id']
        ).order_by('-created_at')


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        user = get_object_or_404(CustomUser, pk=self.kwargs['id'])
        return super().get_context_data(
            user=user,
            main=Main.objects.get(pk=1),
            supporters=CustomUser.objects.filter(team=user.team)
        )
```